# How can I display photos stored on Amazon S3 with Subquery code of Django?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, subquery

I deployed a Web App made by Django to AWS and stored media files to Amazon S3. But when I use Subquery code I wrote below, I can not get the media files and correct urls of Amazon S3.

What should I change my code?

```
user = get_object_or_404(MyUser, pk=5)
subqs = ItemPhoto.objects.filter(item=OuterRef('item')).filter(priority=1) 
queryset = Order.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'orderdetail_orderid', 
        queryset=OrderDetail.objects.select_related('order', 'item').annotate(
                item_photos=Subquery(subqs.values('photo')),
        ),
        to_attr='oor',
    ),
).filter(user=user).order_by('-created_at')

photos1 = [item.item_photos for order in queryset for item in order.oor]
#[sh/Gold Ship/76e91e2d048147c9939d099224e09554.jpg, sh/Epiphaneia/9476dcb430754049b16c62949ecd3839.jpg]

photos2 = [item.item_photos.photo for order in queryset for item in order.oor]
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<console>", line 1, in <listcomp>
# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'photo'

all_photos = ItemPhoto.objects.all()
photos3 = [p.photo for p in all_photos]
#[<ImageFieldFile: sh/Gold Ship/76e91e2d048147c9939d099224e09554.jpg>, <ImageFieldFile: sh/Epiphaneia/9476dcb430754049b16c62949ecd3839.jpg>]

photos4 = [p.photo.url for p in all_photos] # templates can display photos with these urls
#['https://xxxxx.s3.xxxxx.amazonaws.com/media/sh/Gold%20Ship/76e91e2d048147c9939d099224e09554.jpg, 'https://xxxxx.s3.xxxxx.amazonaws.com/media/sh/Epiphaneia/9476dcb430754049b16c62949ecd3839.jpg']
```

template.html

```
{% for order in orders %}
    {% for item in order.oor %}
        <img src="{{ item.item_photos }}">
        # src="sh/Gold Ship/76e91e2d048147c9939d099224e09554.jpg" <- I can not get any photo with this type of url

        <img src="{{ item.item_photos.photo }}">
        # src="" <- None

        <img src="{{ item.item_photos.photo.url }}">
        # src="" <- None

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
def get_itemimage_path(instance, filename): 
    prefix = 'sh{}{}{}'.format(os.sep, instance.item, os.sep) 
    name = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-', '')
    extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
    return '{}{}.{}'.format(prefix, name, extension)

class ItemPhoto(models.Model): 
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="item_photo", verbose_name="item_id",)
    photo = models.ImageField("item_photo", blank=True, 
        upload_to=get_itemimage_path)
    priority = models.IntegerField("priority",)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
if USING_AWS:
    MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/media/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN)
else:
    MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
```

Python 3
Django 4.1

Answer (score 1):

`item.item_photos` seems to be a list of photos. You need to iterate through it and only then to extract photo url

```
{% for item_photo in item.item_photos %}
    <img src="{{ item_photo.photo.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I should have written iterate in my code. Actually, I write iterate in my code as I edited. However, browser shows `src=""`. And `[item.item_photos.photo.url for order in queryset for item in order.oor]` occurs an error, `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'photo'`. So, I guessed my code is something wrong with Subquery.